# Lower bound for binomial theorem for $\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I have this case of binomial theorem:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} r^i (n-r)^{n-i}.
$$

Now, for some reason, we know that $r\le \frac{n}{2}$. Is this enough to conclude that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} r^i (n-r)^{n-i} > \sum_{i=0}^r \binom{n}{i} r^r (n-r)^{n-r} ?
$$

Comment: Are those exponents on the right hand side of your bottom inequality supposed to have $i$ in them, or are they correct as written?

Comment: The exponent are correct as they are written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean $0 < r \le n/2$.  Then $r \le n-r$, so for $0 \le i \le r$ you have
$$ r^{i-r} \ge (n-r)^{i-r}$$
and thus
$$ r^i (n-r)^{n-i} \ge r^r (n-r)^{n-r}$$
Using this for $i=0$ to $r$, and putting additional positive terms on the left for $i=r+1$ to $n$, we do indeed have
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} r^i (n-r)^{n-i} > \sum_{i=0}^r {n \choose i} r^r (n-r)^{n-r} $$